# Can I create a color background for several UIButton's?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have 12 UIButton's (4 rows of 3 in each row) and I would like to create a common background color for all 12 of the UIButton's.  The common background color needs to be a different color from the background color of all of the UIButton's.  I'm creating these buttons in Interface Builder, so ideally I would like to create the common background in there, too, but if that is not possible, then as long as I can continue to create the UIButton's in Interface Builder, I'm willing to code the common background outside of Interface Builder.  I tried doing this by creating a big UILabel in Interface Builder, but I couldn't keep the UILabel in back of the buttons.  The common background needs to stay in back of the buttons.  Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Your question seems to be confusing the background of the `UIButton`s and the background of the `UIView` onto which the `UIButton`s are placed.

Comment: No, I don't think so.  I understand the difference there.  The problem is that I don't want the entire UIView to have this background color...only part of it...the part where the UIButtons are.  The background color of the UIButtons needs to be different from the color of their surrounding area.

Comment: The entire `UIView` has one and only one `backgroundColor`. Each `UIButton` has one and only one `backgroundColor`. If you want only part of the `UIView` to have a certain color, then you'll need to plunk another `UIView` on top of it and change its color. Otherwise, both answers below tell you how to proceed.

Comment: Ok, if I add a new UIView for the area and with the color I want, is there a way to make sure that my UIButton's, which have been created in IB, will always be on top of this new UIView?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do this programmatically, not in IB.

You can create IBOutlets for your 12 buttons, so you can access them from your view controller.

Then, in the `viewDidLoad` method, just create a `UIColor`object, and set it as the `backgroundColor` property of your buttons:

```
- ( void )viewDidLoad
{
    UIColor * bgColor       = [ UIColor redColor ];
    button1.backgroundColor = bgColor;
    button2.backgroundColor = bgColor;
    button3.backgroundColor = bgColor;
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I have already set my UIButton background colors in IB.  That is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Honestly you should be able to do this all in IB.  You don't need a UILabel or anything like that.  Just set the background color for your parent view and for each button.  As far as view ordering goes, Items listed in your view are listed in order of back to front.  Items at the bottom of the tree will be on top of other views listed above them.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want the entire UIView to have this background color...only part of it...the part where the UIButtons are. The background color of the UIButtons needs to be different from the color of their surrounding area.  I don't think I understand what you mean by "bottom of the tree".  What determines the bottom of the tree in IB?